# Touchpad not working properly - Ubuntu 14.04 - Used to work

Tags: 14.04, mouse, touchpad, synaptics

Today, suddenly my Ubuntu 14.04 running on my HP Pavillion DV6 had the touchapd not working properly, at all.

I plugged an external mouse, it worked great.

Problems I'm having with my touchpad:

- jumpy cursor
- scrolling problems
- Right-click panel shows by it self

  - when I scroll using 1 finger, the right click panel pops out by
    itself suddenly
- Mouse lagging

Touchpad became unusable, it's totally not working properly anymore. It worked fine just an hour ago. It might be caused by an update I just did to ubuntu ? Ubuntu asked for an update an hour ago and after that the touchapd problem appeared.

Some Logs:

```
lambasoft@Lambas:~$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Truevision HD                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]



lambasoft@Lambas:~$ xmodmap
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)



lambasoft@Lambas:~$ xmodmap -pp
There are 24 pointer buttons defined.

    Physical        Button
     Button          Code
        1              1
        2              2
        3              3
        4              4
        5              5
        6              6
        7              7
        8              8
        9              9
       10             10
       11             11
       12             12
       13             13
       14             14
       15             15
       16             16
       17             17
       18             18
       19             19
       20             20
       21             21
       22             22
       23             23
       24             24
```

My mousepad if I `cat /proc/bus/input/devices`

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=01b1
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input4
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event5 
B: PROP=1
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e520 30000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=660800011000003


lambasoft@Lambas:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Please let me know if you need any extra logs or details.
Thanks

Comment: You could be suffering from [This bug.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta-lts-trusty/+bug/1558489) Try booting another kernel version

Answer (score -1):

Have you gone into System Settings and checked the values, its possible that they got changed by something in the update.

Also, try rebooting, I know this is the cure for a number of the other OS's problems,  but every once in a while it works even in Linux.